# MySQL - Limit user to products assigned to company

Tags: mysql, database, database-schema

I have `User`, `Company` and `Product` and want to define a relationship between all three.

Companies

- Company A
- Company B

Users

- User A works for Company A
- User B works for Company A
- User C works for Company B

(Many users can work for a company.)

Products

- Company A owns Product A
- Company B owns Product B
- Company B owns Product C

(A Company can own 1 or more products)

How do I define the relationship between `User` and `Product` such that `User A` and `User B` only have access to `Product A` while `User C` has access to only `Product B` and `Product C`?

Many Users can work on many products - but no more than one company can be attached to a product across all Users

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: All your relationships are (presently) "one to many", so you just include a column in each table that references the one object to which each row belongs - so a company column in both the user and product tables. If it's ever possible that a product can be jointly owned by more than one company, or a user work simultaneously for more than one company, then you need to create (two) additional tables in which to record these relationships

Answer (score 0):

use company_id 
(which is the primary key of company table)
as foreign key in both user and product tables. and then use join to relate the both table on the base of this key.

```html
   select user.usernamer, product.productname from user as u join product as p on u.company_id = p.company_id
```